# Showing results from a MySQL query in an HTML table that has a flow layout

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have to fill an html table up with a mysql result. I want the table to be four columns wide and sort the results one in each cell.

The results from MySQL are:

```
-----------------
| Number | Type |
-----------------
|    1   |   A  |
|    2   |   B  |
|    3   |   C  |
|    4   |   D  |
|    5   |   E  |
|    6   |   F  |
-----------------
```

And I want the HTML table to look like this:

```
-----------------
| A | B | C | D |
-----------------
| E | F |   |   |
-----------------
```

I am using PHP to handle the MySQL queries.

Comment: here you will get help when you stuck to do something, but you seems to want complete code>>

Comment: When trying to do a `for` or a `while` to generate the html table and splitting the results each four in one different row. @juergend  @jogesh_p

Comment: if You have problems with `for` or `while`, try `foreach` :D

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect(...);
$qry=mysql_query("select Type from tablename ");
echo "<table>";
$more=true;
while ($more) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($i=0;$i<4;$i++) {
    $fld=mysql_fetch_row($qry);
    if ($fld) $html=$fld[0];
    else {
      $html='&nbsp;'
      $more=false;
    echo "<td>$html</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate your answer. @eugenrieck

Comment: 2 dimensional loop for a 2 dimensional problem

Comment: Where You find second dimension? I see only one array with data from DB and one more loop(ohh) to divide on 4

Comment: The result of our transformation is a 2-dimensional HTML construct as witnessed by <td> and <tr> being the distinct separators for the distinct dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$out = "<table><tr>";
    for(i=0;i<=$max_rows;$i++){
        $out .= ($i%4 ? "" : "</tr>".($i==$max_rows-1 ? "" : "<tr>" ) )."<td>".$result[$i]."</td>";
    }
$out .= "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch the data from the database first:

```
$q = mysql_query("SELECT letters from TABLE");
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($q)) $data[] = $fetch['letters'];
```

then create your table with four coloumns:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <?php $x = 0; for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) : ?>
        <td><?php echo $data[$i]; ?></td>
        <? $x++; ?>
        <? if($x==4) : ?>
            <? $x = 0; ?>
            </tr><tr>
        <? endif; ?>
    <? endfor; ?>
</tr>
</table>
```